# The assignment to variable has no effect?

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, post-increment, pre-increment

When I do this: 
count = ++count;
Why do i get the warning - The assignment to variable count has no effect ?
This means that count is incremented and then assigned to itself or something else ?
Is it the same as just ++count ? 
What happens in count =  count++; ? Why don't I get a warning for this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`count++` and `++count` are both short for `count=count+1`. The assignment is built in, so there's no point to assigning it again. The difference between `count++` (also knows as *postfix*) and `++count` (also known as *prefix*) is that `++count` will happen before the rest of the line, and `count++` will happen after the rest of the line.

If you were to take apart `count=count++`, you would end up with this:

```
    count = count;
    count = count+1;
```

Now you can see why postfix won't give you a warning: something is actually being changed at the end.

If you take apart `count=++count`, you would end up with this:

```
    count = count+1;
    count = count;
```

As you can see, the second line of code is useless, and that's why the compiler is warning you.

Comment: I said short for, not identical to.

Comment: Right - you're answer was more brief when I made that comment (referring to the value returned by the expression). You turned out a great explanation here +1

Comment: why doesn't it through a warning for the first line in the count = count++ example? because that isn't doing anything.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. My answer satisfied OP and I at the time, but in retrospect, I have no idea why prefix would trigger the warning and postfix wouldn't. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Breaking the statement up you are basically writing:

```
++count;
count = count;
```

As you can see count=count does nothing, hence the warning.

Answer (score 3):

the ++ operator is a shortcut for the following `count = count + 1`. If we break your line `count = ++count` it responds to `count = count+1 = count`

Answer (score 3):

To expand a little, count++ is postfix. It takes place after other operations so if you did something like

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
a = b++;
```

a would be 0, b would be 1. However, ++count is prefix if you did

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
a = ++b;
```

then a and b would both be 1. If you just do

```
count++;
```

or

```
++count;
```

then it doesn't matter, but if you are combining it with something else, it will