# Dynamically add table columns?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm looking for a way to dynamically add columns to a vaadin table.

I tried this:

```
private Button createAddColumnButton() {
    Button addProductButton = new Button("Add column");

    addProductButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            count = count++;
            table.addGeneratedColumn("Column "+count, new ColumnGenerator() {

                @Override
                public Object generateCell(final Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
                    String x = "some stuff";
                    return x;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return addProductButton;
}
```

This button allowed me dynamically add a column, however only **one column** before I recieved an error saying I cannot have two columns with the same id. How can I change the ID so it is unique & add lots of columns?

Comment: I have a feeling I need to create a class that implements Column generator and in it set its ID to a random int? maybe...?

Comment: The "column ID" is the first parameter to `addGeneratedColumn()`, so it looks like it is unique in your example. Where is count declared? Is it changed elsewhere? Can you show a full stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Simple change your code to:

```
count = count + 1;
```

**Explenation**

That's beacause assigment

```
count = count++;
```

does not work in the way you expect. Take a look at the following code:

```
public class HelloStackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        count = count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

This prints on standard output 0. You will even get warning (The assignment to variable count has no effect) if you change your code to:

```
count = ++count;
```

You can find even better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639525/the-assignment-to-variable-has-no-effect).

Comment: shame on me for not noticing that ;-)